# wpf conflict between listview and combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, combobox

I have a conflict in my project and I've found a lot about the topic, but nothing that could help me.
In my VM I have a List and a Carmodel SelectedCar. In My view I want the following: A combobox for the CarId, some textboxes and a listview with the cars. One should be able to select a car in the combobox or in the listview, and then populate the textboxes with the right data. So far I have the following code for this in my XAML:

Code for the combobox:

```
        <ComboBox x:Name="KlantNummerCombobox" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"                  ItemsSource="{Binding CarList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCar}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Id" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedKlant.Id,
                  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"
              SelectedValuePath="SelectedKlant.Id" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
              IsEditable="True"
                    />
```

Code fot the ListView:

```
        <ListView BorderThickness="0"
              Grid.Column="1" 
              Grid.Row="7" 
              Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
              ItemsSource="{Binding CarList}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCar}"
              SelectionMode="Single">
            <ListView.View>
            <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="True" ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource DenTroemelGridviewOpmaak}">
                <GridViewColumn Header="Nummer" Width="75" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Naam" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Voornaam" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Model, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

The problem is that there seems to be a problem when i use them both. The combobox works like I want, when I comment the combobox out, the listview works like it should. 
But when i try to use them both, the combobox is still doing what i want it to dot, but when i click in the listview, my textboxes are filled with empty values, like there a new Carmodel created (but when i comment the combobox out again, it works again like i wanted i to). So there seems to be a conflict between these two and i just cant seem to find out what i m doing wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Format the code left.  Why are you binding both SelectedItem and SelectedValue?

Comment: I'm inexperienced, but the thought was Selected item to capture the new carmodel (to show its propertys in the textboxes) and Selected value to fill the combobox with the Id.

Comment: Set IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" on your ListView as well.